# How to avoid severe frame rate drop when using SCNSceneRender prepareObjects:withCompletionHandler:

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I'm working on an iOS AR App using ARKit + SceneKit. The user is able to choose from a list of 3D models which are then placed in the AR Scene. It's pretty similar to [this Apple ARKit sample app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality).

It's also important to mention that my App does not only contain just a few models but hundreds. So preloading all of them would probably not be a very good idea. When loading these models on demand my code looks like this:

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forRessource: "MyModel", ofType: "scn")
let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: modelURL)
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    referenceNode.load()
    self.prepare([referenceNode]) { _ in
        self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(referenceNode)
     }
}
```

Calling `referenceNode.load()` does not cause any issues. It's all handled smoothly in the background. But calling `self.prepare([referenceNode])` causes an immediate frame rate drop to `0` for one or two seconds (depending on the model itself). When removing the `prepare` statement the same thing happens when calling `self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(referenceNode)`.

I noticed exactly the same behavior in the [Apple sample app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality).

I found some similar questions here but no solution that works when loading on demand user initiated 3D models.

Is SceneKit simply not able to add new nodes without freezing or am I missing something essential?

Related Questions:

[How to add SCNNodes without blocking main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180748/how-to-add-scnnodes-without-blocking-main-thread)

[Throttle CPU usage on background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705842/throttle-cpu-usage-on-background-thread/29758556#29758556)

[SceneKit - Adding a new SCNNode to the scene causes severe lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491483/scenekit-adding-a-new-scnnode-to-the-scene-causes-severe-lag)

Comment: Do you found how to solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @Lars Have you been able to solve this issue ? It's almost 2 years later but I'm struggling so solve the same issue described above.

Comment: @mmdumi back then I wasn't able to solve this issue without freezing the ARScene. It might also just be a matter of calling `prepare` at the right time in the user workflow to "hide" the drop in the frame rate from the user.